# Cross Multiplying and Simplifying

Tags: fractions

In a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ls4S8gV6zc) by Michael Penn, at the 3:56 mark, he gets the equation: $$ \frac{4}{2} = \frac{2}{2-x}\Rightarrow 8-4x=4$$ Could someone explain to me how he does this and the process behind it? Thanks for your help! (Im only freshman year of high school so sorry if this question seems basic)

Comment: Cross-multiplying:  if $\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd$, then (multiply both sides by $bd$ to get) $ad=bc$

Comment: Wouldn't the observation $$ \frac{4}{2} = \frac{2}{2-x}\iff \frac{2}{1} = \frac{2}{2-x}$$ lead immediately to the conclusion $1=2-x$?

Comment: Could those voting the close please say what their problem with this question is? This is a reasonable question for someone at this level.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $x\neq2$ and we obtain:
$$\frac{4}{2}\cdot2(2-x)=\frac{2}{2-x}\cdot2(2-x),$$ which gives
$$4(2-x)=4$$ or
$$8-4x=4.$$
Here $2(2-x)$ it's a common denominator of the left side and the right side of the equation.

Comment: +1 elementary yet elegant answer. BTW, do you have an email to correspond in research?